# overload operators new/new[] delete/delete[] globally C++

Tags: c++, valgrind

I have this sample code for overloading operator new and delete

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <new>

#ifdef USE_ZMALLOC
extern "C" {
#include "zmalloc.h"
}
#define m_malloc zmalloc
#define m_free zfree
#else
#ifdef USE_JEMALLOC
#include <jemalloc/jemalloc.h>
#define m_malloc je_malloc
#define m_free je_free
#else
#include "malloc.h"
#define m_malloc std::malloc
#define m_free std::free
#endif
#endif

// C++ requires that operator new return a legitimate pointer
//  even when zero bytes are requested. That's why if (size == 0) size = 1
void* operator new (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) {
  using namespace std;
  if (size == 0) { // Handle 0-byte requests by treating them as 1-byte requests
    size = 1;
  }

  while (true) {
    void* mem = m_malloc(size);

    if (mem != nullptr) {
      return mem;
    } 

    new_handler global_handler = set_new_handler(nullptr);
    set_new_handler(global_handler);

    if (global_handler) {
      (*global_handler)();
    } else {
      throw bad_alloc();
    }

  }
}

void* operator new[] (std::size_t size) throw (std::bad_alloc) {
  return operator new(size);
}

void operator delete (void* ptr) throw() {
  if (ptr == nullptr) {
    return;
  }

  m_free(ptr);
}

void operator delete[] (void* ptr) throw() {
  operator delete(ptr);
}
```

This code is actually working and everything seems to be correct.
My question is: when using valgrind, if I do something like this:

```
int main() {
  Foo** foo = new Foo*[10];

  std::cout << "# " << zmalloc_used_memory() << "." << std::endl;

  delete foo;  // Using wrong delete operator

  return 0;
}
```

valgrind doesn't complain about using the wrong operator delete.
If I use the default operator new/delete pair, valgrind does warn me about the operator delete error.

1) Is there something wrong with my new/delete operators? 
2) Is it normal that valgrind is not warning this kind of errors anymore?

Thx!

Comment: I can't see how operator new[] calls all the constructors of the array's elements and the same for the element destructors for delete[]. Am I missing something?

Comment: In this example I just created the array. I have not initialized the elements inside the array

Comment: @RichardCritten this is how it works. You have a "new expression" which causes operator new and the constructor to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, these are not overloads (since they have exactly the same prototype). These are replacements.

Most likely the problem is that Valgrind does not know that you have replaced these global operators. If you do the replacement in a shared library, Valgrind will see the functions and prototypes and will be able to hook them. However, if the replacements are in your executable itself, you will need to tell Valgrind. I think that this is possible by instrumenting the code, but that's quite difficult. An easier way is to use the Valgrind option --soname-synonyms=somalloc=NONE .

UPDATE:
I'm not sure which version of Valgrind the OP was using, but since Valgrind 3.12.0 (20 October 2016) you don't need any options for user replacements of malloc/new to be detected.

The output that I get with Valgrind 3.20.0 (from git HEAD, June 2022) is

```
==5989== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==5989==    at 0x4030741: operator delete(void*, unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:947)
==5989==    by 0x4012D9: main (in /home/pafloyd/scratch/vg_examples/so_replace_new/srn)
==5989==  Address 0x5328c80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 80 alloc'd
==5989==    at 0x402F103: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:652)
==5989==    by 0x4012BF: main (in /home/pafloyd/scratch/vg_examples/so_replace_new/srn)
```